# Android: delete file taken by camera doesn't work properly (4.4.x)

Tags: android, file

I delete the file (camera file) like that:

```
public static void deleteFile(File file) {
        if (file != null && file.exists()) {
            if (!file.delete()) {
                LogUtils.LOGE(TAG, "Delete file failed: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "Delete file successful: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
```

The delete indicates successful, but if I check on Gallery App on my phone, I can see this strange stuff:
[image]

It's on my Android 4.4.x. With my another mobile on Android 6.x there is no problem.

Could you help me guys?

Comment: Um, what exactly is "this strange stuff"? Please explain, in programming terms, what your symptoms are. Bear in mind that deleting a file will not affect a gallery app until the `MediaStore` realizes that the file is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As @CommonsWare said, since you are saving your file in the public storage, the gallery app will find the file and keep track, after you remove the gallery needs to update the references to now show the image anymore.

To avoid that you should always save your files in the private storage, you can find more info about storages here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html